# EF core - Abstract base class - why there is an error of "No backing field could be found..and the property does not have a setter"?

Tags: ef-core-2.2

I try to make the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Car
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public abstract CarType CarType { get; }

} 
public class SmallCar : Car
{
   public override CarType CarType => CarType.SmallCar;
}
```

And in `OnModelCreating` I do:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasDiscriminator<CarType>("CarType")
            .HasValue<SmallCar>( CarType.SmallCar)

modelBuilder.Entity<SmallCar>().HasBaseType<Car>();
```

But I get the following error:

> No backing field could be found for property 'CarType' of entity type 'Car' and the property does not have a setter..

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing a way for EF to set the value.

Either add a private setter to `CarType` or provide a protected constructor that sets it.

Or... if you don't wish to persist that property to the data store, tell EF to ignore it:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>.Ignore(x => x.CarType);
```

Comment: I do want to persist - i change the property to be virtual with protected set and it worked. 10X